# Using tooltips in form fields

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using this article to create tooltip for form fields :
http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/form.html

it seems that this jQuery function use .tooltip string as default for styling the tooltips.
Is there anyway to change the default CSS class name?

Comment: what do you mean by changing the default CSS? Change the CSS class name or the css style?

Comment: You need to provide some code or an example or something?!

Comment: Just put your own CSS in a file that you load after the one that comes with the jQuery Tools.

Comment: I just wanted to change the CSS class name, for example: as default this function use .tooltip but i want to use .test

Comment: [jQuery UI Tooltip](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#forms)

Comment: @user3067592 if you want to add custom class to tooltip `$('.element').tooltip({ tooltipClass: 'test' });`

Comment: @mdesdev Do you have any reference? it doesn't work

Comment: @user3067592 please include the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [tipClass](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html) property:

```
$("#myform :input").tooltip({
  tipClass: "class"
});
```